# PyPI: how to make the new release as the latest version

Tags: python, pypi

Previously, when I made a new release, the newly released one will be the latest version for the users to install. However, I tried several times for making a new release. The latest version is always the old one.

The "latest version" which is old one (1.1.0):

https://pypi.org/project/ANNOgesic/

I do have the newly released ones:

https://pypi.org/project/ANNOgesic/1.1.4/

It also show that this one is the latest version....

But when I tried to install it, the installed package is 1.1.0 which is the old one.
If I run

```
 pip3 install ANNOgesic==1.1.4
```

I get error messages like these:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> ANNOgesic==1.1.4
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for ANNOgesic==1.1.4

What I do to upload my code is the following

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/*
```

I do not know what happens...

Comment: Try `versioneer` - https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer

Comment: Something is odd because when I click on your first link (project page) and look at the [release history](https://pypi.org/project/ANNOgesic/#history), the latest version shows 1.1.0.  What were the message when you uploaded? I personally prefer to upload with `dist/*1.1.4*`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I checked the package today. The issue was solved after 5h from my release. I guess the PyPI server was maintenance at that moment.